# How to remove values from all columns of a dataframe if one column is having duplicated values?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe say:

```
a 1 roger US
a 2 david US
a 3 mark Canada
b 8 alex Russia
b 5 bob Africa
c 4 Keeth florida
```

I need to keep only the first entry when the first column is duplicated. For e.g. the output should be:

```
a 2 david US
b 8 alex Russia
c 4 Keeth florida
```

How can i achieve this in R?

Comment: How are you handling your database? What have you tried so far? Have you got some examples?

Answer (score 4):

I like the "data.table" approach for this since it includes a "by" argument:

```
library(data.table)
unique(as.data.table(mydf), by = "V1")
#    V1 V2    V3      V4
# 1:  a  1 roger      US
# 2:  b  8  alex  Russia
# 3:  c  4 Keeth florida
```

---

Wit "dplyr", the approach would be:

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% distinct(V1)
#  V1 V2    V3      V4
#1  a  1 roger      US
#2  b  8  alex  Russia
#3  c  4 Keeth florida
```

---

However, as indicated, you can also easily do this in base R with `duplicated`:

```
mydf[!duplicated(mydf$V1), ]
#   V1 V2    V3      V4
# 1  a  1 roger      US
# 4  b  8  alex  Russia
# 6  c  4 Keeth florida
```

---

Here's some sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), 
                       V2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L), 
                       V3 = c("roger", "david", "mark", "alex",
                              "bob", "Keeth"), 
                       V4 = c("US", "US", "Canada", "Russia", 
                              "Africa", "florida")), 
                  .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: For `data.table` you could also do `setkey(setDT(df), V1)[duplicated(df)]` which will probably the winner for a big data set

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
yourdf[!duplicated(yourdf[,1]),]
```

**output:**

```
> yourdf[!duplicated(yourdf[,1]),]

  V1 V2    V3      V4
1  a  1 roger      US
4  b  8  alex  Russia
6  c  4 Keeth florida
```

**data:**

```
yourdf <-structure(list(V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), V2 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L), V3 = c("roger", "david", "mark", "alex", 
"bob", "Keeth"), V4 = c("US", "US", "Canada", "Russia", "Africa", 
"florida")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```